# Using a module inside another module

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a .py file containing some functions. One of the functions requires Python's csv module. Lets call it `foo`.

Here is the thing: if I enter the python shell, import the csv module, write the defitinion of `foo` and use it, everything runs fine.

The problem comes when I try to import `foo` from a custom module. If I enter the python shell, import the csv module, import the module where `foo` is located and try to use it, it will returns an error stating that 'csv' has not been defined (it behaves as if the csv module had not been imported).

I'm wondering if I'm missing some kind of scope behaviour related to imports.

How can I enable `foo` to use the csv module or any other module it requires?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By importing it in the file that defines the `foo` function.

The `foo` function doesn't know to look in the dictionary containing the globals you use in the REPL (where you have imported `csv`). It looks in the globals of it's module (there's other steps here of course), if it doesn't find it there you'll get a `NameError`.

Comment: ευχαριστώ! That will make it for my case. But I'm curious: is there any way to make foo read in the REPL or to pass the csv module to the foo module scope?

Comment: @PabloM Παρακαλώ :)! Yes, you can always attach the csv module to the module containing foo. For example, if `mod.py` is the name of the module and you import it via `import mod` you can then do (after importing `csv`) `mod.csv = csv`. Of course, that's an odd way of doing things.

Comment: I had something like that in mind. Great! Thanks a lot!